# Аналоги Algorius для ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, сеть

Какие аналоги Algorius посоветуете для ubuntu?
От ПО нужно построение карты сети, и некоторые возможности Algorius типа ICMP запросов с выводом графиков, подсвечивание устройств в сети, инвентаризация железа и ПО.